# Analyse a set of User-Agent strings

Tags: logging, useragent

I have a list of User-Agent strings and timestamp. I also have a unique identifier for the user.
What is the best tool for analyzing this type of data?

Comment: Analysing for what? People's interest? Creating an table of most frequently used browsers?

Comment: Yes, browser usage, OS usage, iPhone vs Android, iPad usage etc. And maybe how often users visit the site etc.

Answer (score 0):

Analog can handle this.  With the appropriate logfile format you should be able to get reports by browser, O/S, user, and time reports.  I am not sure it is updated for the latest browsers and platforms.  But it does allow for recoding data, so you should be able to get the results you need.

Comment: That's http://www.analog.cx/ right? Googling for 'analog' yields a few result ;)

Comment: Yes it is.  I've always installed it using the package manager for my systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://piwik.org/

It is open source project trying to provide stuff similar to google analyitics.

It makes all the stats you mention based on logs.

Comment: Thanks Hrvoje, I have seen Piwik, and it looks quite impressive. Didn't know it could get input from log files. Will definitely check that out!